# How to install SDL2 on a Visual Studio 2019 CMake Project (Windows 10)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, sdl-2

I have downloaded the appropriate files for SDL2 `SDL2-devel-2.0.14-VC.zip (Visual C++ 32/64-bit)`, but am unsure of where to begin with installing it.

Comment: I expect any tutorial on how to build a library using CMake would be appropriate. Most third party libraries that use `CMake` to build do so in the exact same way.

Answer (score -1):

By far the easiest way to get libraries in VC++ is [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sdl2.nuget/).

As a cross-platform alternative, you have [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html) and [conan](https://conan.io/center/sdl).